# How to pickle to a different folder on Linux?

Tags: python, linux

When I used Windows, this was my code:

```
save_documents = open("pickled_algos/documents.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(documents, save_documents)
save_documents.close()
```

And what it did is make a second folder called "pickled_algos" and saved it there. Now I'm using Ubuntu Linux and when I write that same code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH/sentimentProjectSaving.py", line 136, in <module>
save_documents = open("pickled_algos/documents.pickle", "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pickled_algos/documents.pickle'
```

How do I do the same thing I did in Windows, but on Linux?

EDIT: When I remove "pickled_algos/" then it works, the again the problem is that is saves into the same folder where the python file is.

Comment: Create the directory first.

Comment: @melpomene I've made a folder in the project's folder and it still says the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be because you're using a relative path instead of an absolute path. Specifically, your error mentions that the directory can't be found so you should first check if the directory exists.

```
import os

path = 'your path'

# Create target Directory if doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
    print("Directory created ")
else:    
    print("Directory already exists")
```

Comment: I have manually created the folder inside of the project parent folder. Still didn't work. Even when I just try to open it with "rb" instead of "wb" it still doesn't work. How do I make it find my other directory?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by find other directory. I think you need to give it the absolute path. Go into your created folder and type `pwd` to give you the absolute path

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't understand you correctly before. It works now that I use the absolute path. Thank you for that.

Comment: @pantank14 You're probably looking at the wrong directory.